# What's your favorite maven repository server?

Tags: maven, repository, nexus, archiva

HI,Which maven repository server do you prefer? Apache archiva , Nexus or other?
and why?

Comment: You are asking the preference of programmers, so you may want to also try programmers.stackexchange

Comment: @Matt - this would get closed on Programmers' as well. "Which technology is better" questions are generally off topic. They only time they're not is if there's a specific requirement that needs to be met.

Comment: @Chrisf But he asked "do you prefer?", which seems to me  more likely to produce answers of "I like x because it does Y".  I know I myself have found new and better tools from questions of this kind.  But if thats still considered out of scope then I guess thats that :(

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used archiva so far but Artefactory and Nexus. With artifactory we discovered a problem when deploying large files (some hundred megs). This could - as far as I remember - not be solved in general because somehow it was bound to the memory that was available to the jvm but with Nexus one has the possibiliy to use a different upload mechanism via

```
<server>
    <id>...</id>
    <username>...</username>
    <password>...</password>
    <configuration>
        <wagonProvider>httpclient</wagonProvider>
    </configuration>
</server>
```

that's one point why we prefer Nexus.

Second point: In the new 1.9 version Nexus comes with the archetype catalog plugin which gives you an automatic update of the archetypes you have deployed - as far as I know this is not possible with artifactory (but perhaps something has been done there as well).

So far we're happy with Nexus...

Answer (score 0):

I like the SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository. Here's the pertinent section of their FAQ that describes usage with Maven:

http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/faq;jsessionid=3E8902A07670379604AA54148A492D1D.jvm1#q8